# How to prevent native fullscreen video player on Opera Mobile for Android using Flowplayer?

Tags: android, fullscreen, opera, flowplayer, opera-mobile

I am building the Flowplayer video player through Javascript dynamically, and on all browsers currently I am getting the expected result, except for Opera Mobile. I am using the `flowplayer.conf.native_fullscreen` configuration setting to disable the fullscreen when necessary. I have tested this by setting it globally to be false, and on Chrome for Android, and Firefox for Android, this disables the native fullscreen, but for Opera mobile it still continues to force fullscreen.

My question is if anyone knows whether this is an Opera issue, or a Flowplayer issue. I can post an excerpt from my code if it seems like it might be implementation on my end, but my assumption so far has been that there might be some quirk with Opera Mobile that I am unaware of.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's specific to Flowplayer, as I'm having exactly the same problem with Opera Mobile for Android (Version 26.0.1619.84037 running on Jellybean), and I'm using jwPlayer. Opera insists on jumping into fullscreen video mode as soon as you hit "play", even when the media being played is just an mp3 - driving me nuts!